# How to show relation between two boxes containing same data in two different treemaps

Tags: highcharts, treemap

I am using treemaps for a comparison purpose. I am using highchart.com for visualization.

I am showing two different treemaps side by side and hence providing a way of comparison for users. I want to link two same boxes in different treemaps. For example, I have two different treemaps and both have word "Bananas" in common. I want that when I hover on Box containing "Bananas" in first treemap, it highlights the same box of "Bananas" in 2nd treemap.

Is this even possible?

here is the code which generates the treemap.

```js
Highcharts.chart('treemap1', {
  series: [{
    type: "treemap",
    layoutAlgorithm: 'stripes',
    alternateStartingDirection: true,
    levels: [{
      level: 1,
      layoutAlgorithm: 'sliceAndDice',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        align: 'left',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        style: {
          fontSize: '15px',
          fontWeight: 'bold'
        }
      }
    }],
    data: [{
      id: 'A',
      name: 'Apples',
      color: "#EC2500"
    }, {
      id: 'B',
      name: 'Bananas',
      color: "#ECE100"
    }, {
      id: 'O',
      name: 'Oranges',
      color: '#EC9800'
    }, {
      name: 'Anne',
      parent: 'A',
      value: 5
    }, {
      name: 'Rick',
      parent: 'A',
      value: 3
    }, {
      name: 'Peter',
      parent: 'A',
      value: 4
    }, {
      name: 'Anne',
      parent: 'B',
      value: 4
    }, {
      name: 'Rick',
      parent: 'B',
      value: 10
    }, {
      name: 'Peter',
      parent: 'B',
      value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Anne',
      parent: 'O',
      value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Rick',
      parent: 'O',
      value: 3
    }, {
      name: 'Peter',
      parent: 'O',
      value: 3
    }, {
      name: 'Susanne',
      parent: 'Kiwi',
      value: 2,
      color: '#9EDE00'
    }]
  }],
  title: {
    text: 'Treemap 1'
  }
});
Highcharts.chart('treemap2', {
  series: [{
    type: "treemap",
    layoutAlgorithm: 'stripes',
    alternateStartingDirection: true,
    levels: [{
      level: 1,
      layoutAlgorithm: 'sliceAndDice',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        align: 'left',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        style: {
          fontSize: '15px',
          fontWeight: 'bold'
        }
      }
    }],
    data: [{
      id: 'A',
      name: 'Apples',
      color: "#EC2500"
    }, {
      id: 'B',
      name: 'Bananas',
      color: "#ECE100"
    }, {
      id: 'O',
      name: 'Oranges',
      color: '#EC9800'
    }, {
      name: 'Anne',
      parent: 'A',
      value: 5
    }, {
      name: 'Rick',
      parent: 'A',
      value: 3
    }, {
      name: 'Peter',
      parent: 'A',
      value: 4
    }, {
      name: 'Anne',
      parent: 'B',
      value: 4
    }, {
      name: 'Rick',
      parent: 'B',
      value: 10
    }, {
      name: 'Peter',
      parent: 'B',
      value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Anne',
      parent: 'O',
      value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Rick',
      parent: 'O',
      value: 3
    }, {
      name: 'Peter',
      parent: 'O',
      value: 3
    }, {
      name: 'Susanne',
      parent: 'Kiwi',
      value: 2,
      color: '#9EDE00'
    }]
  }],
  title: {
    text: 'Treemap 2'
  }
});
```

```css
.treemap-chart {
  float: left;
  width: 50%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/treemap.js"></script>
<div id="treemap1" class="treemap-chart"></div>
<div id="treemap2" class="treemap-chart"></div>
```

Image of the output here: 
[codeoutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cogak.png)

Comment: Let me attach a screenshot

Comment: @ewolden, please see this screenshot. https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1kgJ.png

We have two different treemaps, both are displaying almost same information. I have first verb "apply" in first treemap, now I want that, when I hover on "apply", word "apply" on other treemap get highlighted in any possible way. 

let me know if you need more details

Comment: @ewolden, I have added the code, refresh

Comment: hey, there is alot of data being fetched in this chart from different locations, the chart is dynamic and data is coming from input forms.its not a chunk of code but a whole application. I can't add all of code here. it would be a mess. :)

Comment: Thanks, let me organize code and i ll share it

Comment: @ewolden, I have updated the code and screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by setting the [`state`](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#setState) of a the hovered point in the [`mouseOver`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.point.events.mouseOver) event and removing the `state` in the [`mouseOut`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.point.events.mouseOut) event. Like this for the first chart, and the same for second chart changing the variable `chart2` to `chart1`:

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    point: {
      events: {
        mouseOver: function(event) {
          for (var i = 0; i < chart2.series[0].data.length; i++) {
            if (chart2.series[0].data[i].name == event.target.name && chart2.series[0].data[i].parent == event.target.parent) {
              chart2.series[0].data[i].setState('hover')
            }
          }
        },
        mouseOut: function(event) {
          for (var i = 0; i < chart2.series[0].data.length; i++) {
            if (chart2.series[0].data[i].name == event.target.name && chart2.series[0].data[i].parent == event.target.parent) {
              chart2.series[0].data[i].setState('')
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
```

```js
var chart1 = Highcharts.chart('treemap1', {
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      point: {
        events: {
          mouseOver: function(event) {
            for (var i = 0; i < chart2.series[0].data.length; i++) {
              if (chart2.series[0].data[i].name == event.target.name && chart2.series[0].data[i].parent == event.target.parent) {
                chart2.series[0].data[i].setState('hover')
              }
            }
          },
          mouseOut: function(event) {
            for (var i = 0; i < chart2.series[0].data.length; i++) {
              if (chart2.series[0].data[i].name == event.target.name && chart2.series[0].data[i].parent == event.target.parent) {
                chart2.series[0].data[i].setState('')
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    type: "treemap",
    layoutAlgorithm: 'stripes',
    alternateStartingDirection: true,
    levels: [{
      level: 1,
      layoutAlgorithm: 'sliceAndDice',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        align: 'left',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        style: {
          fontSize: '15px',
          fontWeight: 'bold'
        }
      }
    }],
    data: [{
      id: 'A',
      name: 'Apples',
      color: "#EC2500"
    }, {
      id: 'B',
      name: 'Bananas',
      color: "#ECE100"
    }, {
      id: 'O',
      name: 'Oranges',
      color: '#EC9800'
    }, {
      name: 'Anne',
      parent: 'A',
      value: 5
    }, {
      name: 'Rick',
      parent: 'A',
      value: 3
    }, {
      name: 'Peter',
      parent: 'A',
      value: 4
    }, {
      name: 'Anne',
      parent: 'B',
      value: 4
    }, {
      name: 'Rick',
      parent: 'B',
      value: 10
    }, {
      name: 'Peter',
      parent: 'B',
      value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Anne',
      parent: 'O',
      value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Rick',
      parent: 'O',
      value: 3
    }, {
      name: 'Peter',
      parent: 'O',
      value: 3
    }, {
      name: 'Susanne',
      parent: 'Kiwi',
      value: 2,
      color: '#9EDE00'
    }]
  }],
  title: {
    text: 'Treemap 1'
  }
});

var chart2 = Highcharts.chart('treemap2', {
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      point: {
        events: {
          mouseOver: function(event) {
            for (var i = 0; i < chart1.series[0].data.length; i++) {
              if (chart1.series[0].data[i].name == event.target.name && chart1.series[0].data[i].parent == event.target.parent) {
                chart1.series[0].data[i].setState('hover')
              }
            }
          },
          mouseOut: function(event) {
            for (var i = 0; i < chart1.series[0].data.length; i++) {
              if (chart1.series[0].data[i].name == event.target.name && chart1.series[0].data[i].parent == event.target.parent) {
                chart1.series[0].data[i].setState('')
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    type: "treemap",
    layoutAlgorithm: 'stripes',
    alternateStartingDirection: true,
    levels: [{
      level: 1,
      layoutAlgorithm: 'sliceAndDice',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        align: 'left',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        style: {
          fontSize: '15px',
          fontWeight: 'bold'
        }
      }
    }],
    data: [{
      id: 'A',
      name: 'Apples',
      color: "#EC2500"
    }, {
      id: 'B',
      name: 'Bananas',
      color: "#ECE100"
    }, {
      id: 'O',
      name: 'Oranges',
      color: '#EC9800'
    }, {
      name: 'Anne',
      parent: 'A',
      value: 5
    }, {
      name: 'Rick',
      parent: 'A',
      value: 3
    }, {
      name: 'Peter',
      parent: 'A',
      value: 4
    }, {
      name: 'Anne',
      parent: 'B',
      value: 4
    }, {
      name: 'Rick',
      parent: 'B',
      value: 10
    }, {
      name: 'Peter',
      parent: 'B',
      value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Anne',
      parent: 'O',
      value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Rick',
      parent: 'O',
      value: 3
    }, {
      name: 'Peter',
      parent: 'O',
      value: 3
    }, {
      name: 'Susanne',
      parent: 'Kiwi',
      value: 2,
      color: '#9EDE00'
    }]
  }],
  title: {
    text: 'Treemap 2'
  }
});
```

```css
 .treemap-chart {
   float: left;
   width: 50%
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/treemap.js"></script>
<div id="treemap1" class="treemap-chart"></div>
<div id="treemap2" class="treemap-chart"></div>
```

**Working jsfiddle example:** https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/czn1rjxu/2/